# Not starting NFS kernel daemon: no support in current kernel

Tags: nfs

I installed NFS on a new ubuntu 18.04 install. I did:

```
apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
add folder to share to /etc/exports: /home/share *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
service nfs-kernel-server start
```

But after this I get this error:

[warn] Not starting NFS kernel daemon: no support in current kernel. ... (warning).

I have searched in google and get no solution. Anyone can give me an advice?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try out
`sudo /sbin/modprobe -v nfsd` ?

This will attempt to load the nfsd module in the kernel.